# Trying to search WikiNews

Tags: json, mediawiki-api

I'm trying to search WikiNews, both for specific news stories and for the latest headlines.  I've been reading about the MediaWiki API (https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page), but it doesn't seem to map to what I'm trying to do.

Taking two examples, I need to be able to get the latest headlines (ideally for a specific region (United States, France, Great Britain etc) and for a specific topic (Finance, Sport, Media etc), but right now I'd settle for just getting the latest stories regardless.  I've tried a couple of things:

1. `https://en.wikinews.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=categories&clprop=timestamp&format=json`
   just returns `batchcomplete`
2. `http://en.wikinews.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=recentchanges&rnnamespace=0` looks like it might be more promising, but only if I could filter only to show news stories - and show a good deal more than it currently does.  Clearly it would also be desirable to add parameters for location / story type in the query rather than filtering them after the list is received.

With regard to searching, I've had even less luck.  I've tried searching on a topic that I know is ~~causing trouble~~ making the news:

1. `https://en.wikinews.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Donald_Trump&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=json&redirects&continue` the return is not a list of stories!

Has anyone searched WikiNews?  Does anyone have any suggestions to achieve what I need to do?

Comment: The search API endpoints are [search](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Search), [geosearch](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:GeoData#API) and [opensearch](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Opensearch) (see [API:Search and discovery](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Search_and_discovery) for an overview). I don't think you can search for recent events. MediaWiki hasn't been adapted much to the needs of WikiNews.

Comment: Damn.  Do you know of anything which might work better, whilst still providing open and free content?

Comment: I don't. You can probably put a recent article search together for Wikinews (e.g. use [date category](https://en.wikinews.org/wiki/Category:News_articles_by_date) intersections) but it will take some effort.

Comment: Hmm.  Any suggestions?  Or has anyone else any suggestions (put 'em in an answer so that I can give a tick and up vote!)

Comment: @headbanger Have you found a way to get the latest headlines from Wikinews?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[action=query&format=json&list=search&redirects=1&srsearch="Donald Trump" -incategory:disputed incategory:"August_25, _2016|August_24,_2016|August_23,_2016|August_22,_2016|August_21,_2016|August_20,_2016|August_19,_2016|August_18,_2016"&srnamespace=0&srenablerewrites=1](https://en.wikinews.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox#action=query&format=json&list=search&redirects=1&srsearch=%22Donald+Trump%22+-incategory%3Adisputed+incategory%3A%22August+25%2C+2016%7CAugust+24%2C+2016%7CAugust+23%2C+2016%7CAugust+22%2C+2016%7CAugust+21%2C+2016%7CAugust+20%2C+2016%7CAugust+19%2C+2016%7CAugust+18%2C+2016%22&srnamespace=0&srenablerewrites=1) will search for articles from the last few days mentioning Trump. (See [full docs](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:CirrusSearch) on what keywords can be used in a search query.)

Most of your examples do not actually generate a list (you can see from the lack of a `list` parameter); they expect one or more article name via the `titles` parameter and return information about those. Your second example is valid (except the correct parameter name is `rcnamespace`) but that returns recently edited articles, which is a very random way of trying to find news on a topic.

In general it seems like you are trying to randomly guess what the API modules do. Did you miss the [docs](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page) and [sandbox](https://en.wikinews.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox)?

Comment: Thanks for this - that's a huge help.  I really didn't understand the docs (on the basis of the attempts I made above!)